# Will calling tkinter.after(function) over and over cause a stackoverflow?

Tags: python, tkinter, recursion

I'm creating a GUI that shows data that I want to be updated every 10 seconds with tkinter.

Now you can't use

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

master = tk.Tk()

while True:
    master.show(global variable that has been changed from different thread)
    time.sleep(10)

master.mainloop()
```

because the mainloop would never run. Now a solution would be to put the code in a function and call that function with master.after() like this

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

def updateValue():
    master.show(global variable that has been changed from different thread)
    master.after(10000, updateValue)

updateValue()
master.mainloop()
```

Now I'm wondering if this would cause a stackoverflow issue because recursively calling a function over and over would, right?

Also if this is not an issue is it because the after method from tkinter takes care of it or is python optimizing for tail recursion?

Edit: I tried it and using the tkinter.after method it seems to run forever while it would fail after roughly 1000 calls with normal recursion. I would still be interested in why and how that is if anybody has an idea.

Comment: Well, have you tried it? Try calling it every 100ms and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will calling tkinter.after(function) over and over cause a stackoverflow?

When done properly, no. Though, if you're scheduling something every second to run in a month or year, you might eventually run out of memory.

> Now I'm wondering if this would cause a stackoverflow issue because recursively calling a function over and over would, right?

Recursively calling a function over and over would, but that's not what you're doing with `after`. Using `after` isn't technically recursion. With `after`, all you're doing is adding something to a queue. Each time the function is called, an item is removed from the queue. With your code, and assuming there's no other code calling `after`, the queue never gets any bigger than 1.

> Also if this is not an issue is it because the after method from tkinter takes care of it or is python optimizing for tail recursion?

It's being taken care of by the embedded tcl interpreter. Python does no optimization here. And again, this isn't recursion.